# Inserting data from <option> to Database in Laravel 5.8

Tags: html, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to insert data into a database with an option menu.

```
<select class="form-control" name="tim">
    @foreach ($tim as $t)
        <option value="{{ $t->id }}">{{ $t->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

and this the controller

```
$data=new Modelverif();
$data->id_profil=$request->id;
$data->$id_pegawai=$request->get('tim');
$data->save();
```

how to input database with option menu with array?

Comment: `$request->tim` would have sufficed. Aso, if you are going to update an existing model, you would need pull that from database first. You can use `find($id)` or `where('id, $id)->first()` or a couple of other options.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: what did u receive when you put dd($request->get('tim')); in the controller's function.  ?

Comment: `$data->$id_pegawai` where is the variable  `$id_pegwai` coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Blade.php**

```
   <select class="form-control" name="tim">
      @foreach ($tim as $t)
      <option value="{{ $t->id }}">{{ $t->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
```

**the controller**

```
$data=new Modelverif();
$data->id_profil=$request->id;
$data->$id_pegawai=$request->tim;  //Or $data->$id_pegawai= $request->input('tim'); 
$data->save();
```

Comment: please give upvote this answer thank you..if its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    $data=new Modelverif();
    $data->id_profil=$request->id;
    // assuming you have column name in $id_pegawai 
    $data->$id_pegawai= $request->input('tim'); 
    // or, 
    // $data->$id_pegawai= $request->tim;



    $data->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you need to convert your select into multiple choice.

```
<select class="form-control" multiple name="tim">
```

it will allow you choose mulitple values from select and give an array of values when you post the data